# How to bind a list of non-MonoBehaviour objects to manager class using Zenject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I am using Zenject for dependency injection in my game, and I am in an impasse.

Let me describe my current setup:

I have several characters with their own `GameObjectContext` and `CharacterInstaller` responsible for injecting a `CharacterController` into a `CharacterPresenter`.

```cs
public class CharacterInstaller : MonoInstaller<CharacterInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<CharacterInstaller>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
    }
}
```

```cs
// PLAIN C# class
public class CharacterController : <some_interfaces>
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CharacterPresenter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController characterController;

    [Inject]
    public void InjectDependencies( CharacterController characterController )
    {
        this.characterController = characterController;
    }

    public void Foo() => characterController.Foo();
}
```

---

What I would like to do is to also inject all the instances of the `CharacterController` class into a "Manager" class using [List Bindings](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject#list-bindings). This manager is not a parent of my characters, and I may need several managers.

```cs
public class CharactersManager
{
    private List<Character> characters;

    public CharactersManager( List<Character> characters)
    {
        this.characters = characters;
    }

    public void MakeCharactersDoSomething()
    {
        foreach ( Character character in characters)
            character.Foo();
    }
}
```

The closer things I found to solve my problem were:

• Attach a `ZenjectBinding` component to my Character and specify the context I need.
→ Can't work because `CharacterController` is a plain C# class and the `ZenjectBinding` only binds components

• Declare a `Context` in the `CharacterInstaller` and call `OtherContext.Container.Bind...`
→ Fails because `OtherContext.Container` is null

• Call `Container.Bind<CharacterController>().FromComponentsInHierarchy()` in my manager installer
→ Does not work because `CharacterController` is not a component

• Using a factory
→ I can't use it since my objects are meant to be placed at edit time in the editor

• Using `Container.ParentContainers` in my `CharacterInstaller`
→ Can't use it because my manager is not a parent container of my `CharacterInstaller.Container`

I am open to suggestions, maybe a refactoring of my setup if needed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution, but it does not feel very great.

In an installer attached to the scene context, bind a `List<CharacterController>`

```cs
public class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller<GameInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<List<CharacterController>>().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

And in the `CharacterInstaller`, add the instantiated character to the injected list

```cs
public class CharacterInstaller : MonoInstaller<CharacterInstaller>
{
    private List<CharacterController> characters;

    [Inject]
    public void InjectDependencies( List<CharacterController> characters )
    {
        this.characters = characters;
    }

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<CharacterInstaller>()
            .AsSingle()
            .OnInstantiated<CharacterController>( ( context, character ) => characters.Add( character ) )
            .NonLazy();
    }
}
```